# Why did Paul use the word "boast" so many times in 2 Corinthians?

Tags: romans

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2744&t=KJV&bn=47#lexResults:

> Strong's Number G2744 matches the Greek καυχάομαι (kauchaomai),
> which occurs **21 times** in 17 verses in '2Co' in the Greek concordance of the KJV

https://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=jesus&t=KJV#s=s_primary_47_1:

> "jesus"
> occurs **20 times** in 16 verses in the book of '2Co' in the KJV

The word *boast* appears 21 times. In comparison, the word *Jesus* appears 20 times.

> 2 Corinthians 12:1
> I must go on boasting. Although there is nothing to be gained, I will go on to visions and revelations from the Lord. ...
> 11
> I have made a fool of myself, but you drove me to it. I ought to have been commended by you, for I am not in the least inferior to the "super-apostles," even though I am nothing.

What was this Paul's obsession with boasting in 2 Corinthians?  Signs of insecurity?

Comment: I have not made any statement concerning Paul whom I respect greatly.

Comment: Pretty good. You read my mind somewhat but I have not make any statements, only questions which allow you to prove the opposite. I should stress again that I'm no where near the stature of Paul.

Comment: This is an insightful question regarding Paul's self-professed knowledge of God. In 2 Corinthians 12, it appears that Paul is attempting to fulfill Jeremiah 9 referencing his "boast" in "the truth". - Thanks for sharing, Tony Chan!

Comment: Your post uses the word "boast" three times, but the word "Jesus" only two times. Are you obsessed or insecure? (Answer: Of course not. A strict word count tells you very little. You have to actually read what a person is saying...)

Comment: Some of us think there are several cases of two different people going by the same name. Paul is one of them. In my Bible, I separate the words of the 'true Paul' who actually *says* something, from the blathering of the 'false Paul'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did Paul use the word "boast" so many times in 2 Corithians? - Paul is referencing Jeremiah 9:22-23.

In 2 Corinthians 12:1-6, we read Paul's fulfillment of Jeremiah 9:22-23 in order to testify that Yeshua (Jesus) of Nazareth is the Messiah, and see Paul now "understands and knows Him" - making 2 Corithians 12:6 fulfill Jeremiah 9:23.

- In Hebrew the word for #Boast is "Yitehallel" ( יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל), used three times in Jeremiah 9:22 [MT].
- Jeremiah 9:22 [MT] : "Thus says YHVH : Let not the wise man boast of his wisdom, nor the strong man boast of his strength, nor the rich man boast of his riches." (כֹּ֣ה | אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֗ה אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֚ל חָכָם֙ בְּחָכְמָת֔וֹ וְאַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל הַגִּבּ֖וֹר בִּגְבֽוּרָת֑וֹ אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל עָשִׁ֖יר בְּעָשְׁרֽוֹ )

Jeremiah 9:23 [MT] :
"But let him that boasts exult in this, that he understands and knows me, for I am YHVH who practices kindness, justice and righteousness on the earth; for in these things I delight, says YHVH." (כִּ֣י אִם־בְּזֹ֞את יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל הַמִּתְהַלֵּ֗ל הַשְׂכֵּל֘ וְיָדֹ֣עַ אוֹתִי֒ כִּי אֲנִ֣י יְהֹוָ֔ה עֹ֥שֶׂה חֶ֛סֶד מִשְׁפָּ֥ט וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָ֑רֶץ כִּֽי־בְאֵ֥לֶּה חָפַ֖צְתִּי נְאֻם־יְהֹוָֽה )

2 Corinthians 12:6 [NIV] - "Even if I should choose to boast, I would not be a fool, because I would be speaking the truth."

Paul uses the word "truth" (ἀλήθειαν) in 2 Corinthians 12:6 alluding to the truth of Jeremiah 9:23 that YHVH "practices kindness, justice and righteousness on the earth".

Answer (score 4):

It is apposite that the OP aims some comments at the apostle in this question,

- that Paul uses the name ‘Jesus’ only a little more than the word ‘boast’
- and that, thus, the apostle is either ‘obsessional’ or . . .
- exhibiting ‘insecurity’.

Apposite to the question . . .  because that is exactly the kind of treatment the Corinthians were offering to Paul in return for him having preached the gospel to them, and in return for his care and love and exhortation and watchfulness over their souls.

---

For eighteen months (Acts 18:11) Paul laboured among these people, teaching them the gospel and ministering spiritually to them, probably, as he often did, earning a living from tent-making at the same time, since he usually preferred not to be ‘chargeable’ to those to whom he ministered and, since he had chosen not to marry but to remain a single man, that he might evangelise extensively, he was able to support himself and also to minister to others, without being a burden to any.

But after a time, Paul was constrained to write a letter to the Corinthian church as the house of Chloe (1 Corinthians 1:11) had intimated to Paul that there were contentions. Also, Paul was told of a man who had married the wife of his (divorced or deceased) father, a thing that self-respecting heathen gentiles would not do. And there was disorder : the Lord’s supper, the covering of the head, the wrongful organising of meetings.

Yet there were other undercurrents, some of them directed at Paul himself, thus in the first letter he says ‘With me , it is a very small thing that I should be judged of you’, 1, 4:3. It is a thing, yes. But a very small thing. For did the word of God come out from these people, 1,14:36, or did it not come ‘unto them only’ ?

Had they preached to Paul the glorious gospel, that they should then offer such ‘small’ criticisms and judgments against him ? Or was it not, rather, by the grace of God, that Paul had travelled all the way from Antioch to them to inform them of a gospel that they, hitherto, knew nothing about . .

. . . .  and stayed eighteen months, selflessly ministering to them.

Thus Paul writes again to them and commends them, first, telling them to invite the penitent man back into their company and to treat him with love, 2, 2:6, and telling them that with anguish of heart and tears he had written the first to them.

But, it is evident that there is still attitude towards Paul, yet he speaks with grace towards them and tells them that it is not the ministry that is straitened towards them, 2, 5:12, but they, themselves who are straitened within them themselves.

Thus he urges them not to be unequally yoked with unbelievers, to come out from them and to be a separate company. And he warns them that he would prefer not to be ‘bold against some’ of them who thought of the ministers of the gospel as if they ‘walked according to the flesh’, 2,10:2.

Rather he says to them, ‘Do ye look on the outward appearance ?’ It was they who had a carnal outlook and had suspicious thoughts of the ministers of the gospel.

And it is at this point that Paul asserts his authority, as a minister of the word and as an apostle, and he says that though he boasts of his authority - which the Lord has given him - yet should he not be ashamed, 2, 10:8.

And with this, he then mentions what some were saying of him : For his letters, they were saying, 2, 10: 10, are weighty but his bodily presence is weak and his speech contemptible.

Paul changes his tone and warns this person : Such as we are in word b y letters, such also, in deed, when we are present.

So, no, Paul is not ‘insecure’. In the slightest.

Nor is he ‘obsessed’ with boasting.

But when some would think to belittle the ministers of Christ and the apostles, chosen particularly by the Lord to inaugurate the New Testament and to establish the church in the beginning, then Paul asserts his authority and boasts (though *kauchesis* and *kauchema* are as much rendered ‘glorying’ and ‘rejoicing’ and I think that meaning to be more appropriate than ‘boast’ myself - or, perhaps ‘exalt’ might be even better).

Paul rises above petty criticism and small-minded insults. He is a bigger man than to be affected by such petulant and sour-minded attitudes. He is perfectly capable of dealing with such bad manners, if it becomes necessary.

For God had dealt with him, mightily, and if any said he were a Jew : why, so could Paul ! And if any asserted himself among the Corinthian church and boasted that he was a (self-made, perhaps) ‘minister of Christ’ then so could Paul the apostle abundantly boast, also.

And thus does he, for two whole chapters, 2,11 and 2,12, asserting what Christ has done through him and exalting in the example that Christ has given to the whole church, in himself, of zeal and love and ministry.

‘Obsessed and insecure’ ? : I think the two Corinthian epistles, taken together, say - Not so !

Answer (score 3):

**Why did Paul use the word “boast” so many times in 2 Corinthians?**

Usually,  it is unpleasant to hear a person brag or boast about himself.  A person might brag by the very tone of his voice, or by his swaggering manner, causing others to ask, “Who does he think he is?”

Because boasting is unloving, intimidating, and hurtful, we find that God's Word is counseling Christians against it. What really matters is not our abilities,or our wealth but the kind of person we are. Of what value are our superiorities or talents if we are selfish, rude, and arrogant? Paul wrote;

1 Corinthians 4:7  (NASB)

> 7 For who regards you as superior? What do you have that you did not
> receive? And if you did receive it, why do you boast as if you had not
> received it?

**Immaturity.**

Boasting or bragging is a sign of immaturity and appreciating it will help us avoid it. It should be noted that the   Greek word  "νηπιος" ne-pios (rendered child or babe) in the text mentioned below is associated  with "Immaturity"

1 Corinthians 13:11  (NASB)

> 11 When I was a child, I used to speak like a child, think like a
> child, reason like a child; when I became a man, I did away with
> childish things.

**Unloving.**

Bragging is unloving, what we have we have received it from God, so taking credit for what belongs to him is most unloving.

1 Corinthians 13:4 (NASB)

> 4 Love is patient, love is kind and is not jealous; love does not brag
> and is not arrogant,

**Exalting ourselves**

By bragging, we are exalting ourselves above others and may well arouse jealousy and envy, and certainly, that is not loving, for it makes others unhappy. It is bound to be that way, for the effect of exalting ourselves is to lower others by comparison or in relation to us.

**Boasting if often used as a means of intimidation.**

The giant Philistine "Goliath" sought to strike fear in the young lad David. 1 Samuel 17:41-51

https://classic.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2017%3A41-51&version=NASB;NET